# How to generate a create table script for an existing table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I generate a create table script for an existing table in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 709, accepted):

Use one of the following queries in sql tab:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
SHOW CREATE TABLE database.tablename;
```

To view full query
There is this Hyperlink named +Options left above, There select Full Texts

Comment: Are there arguments I can add to export it to a file?

Answer (score 54):

Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>;` query.

Answer (score 23):

### Mysqladmin can do the job of saving out the create table script.

**Step 1, create a table, insert some rows:**

```
create table penguins (id int primary key, myval varchar(50))
insert into penguins values(2, 'werrhhrrhrh')
insert into penguins values(25, 'weeehehehehe')
select * from penguins
```

**Step 2, use mysql dump command:**

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments --host=your_database_hostname_or_ip.com -u your_username --password=your_password your_database_name penguins > penguins.sql
```

**Step 3, observe the output in penguins.sql:**

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `penguins`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `penguins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `myval` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

The output is cluttered by a number of executional-condition tokens above and below.  You can filter them out if you don't want them in the next step.

**Step 4 (Optional), filter out those extra executional-condition tokens this way:**

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments --compact --host=your_database_hostname_or_ip.com -u your_username --password=your_password your_database_name penguins > penguins.sql
```

**Which produces final output:**

```
eric@dev /home/el $ cat penguins.sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `penguins`;
CREATE TABLE `penguins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `myval` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 17):

Run query is sql tab

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName
```

Click on

> +Options -> Choose Full texts -> Click on Go

Copy Create Table query and paste where you want to create new table.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on displaying full text, wasn't sure why it was getting cut off until I saw your answer.

Comment: @Dymas you have to choose full texts to show full query. i have done same to see full query.

Answer (score 10):

You can query information_schema.columns directly:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table' AND table_schema = 'your_database'
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the following query in sql tab: `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;`
2. Press GO button
3. After show table, above the table ( +options ) Hyperlink.
4. Press +options Hyperlink then appear some options select (Full
   texts) press GO button.
5. Show sql query.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a late reply. But it may help others. It is very simple in MY SQL Workbench ( I am using Workbench version 6.3 and My SQL Version 5.1 Community edition): Right click on the table for which you want the create script, select 'Copy to Clipboard --> Create Statement' option. Simply paste in any text editor you want to get the create script.

Comment: This is outdated and won't work without further configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP Function.

Of course query function ($this->model) you have to change to your own.

```
/**
 * Creating a copy table based on the current one
 * 
 * @param type $table_to_copy
 * @param type $new_table_name
 * @return type
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function create($table_to_copy, $new_table_name)
{
    $sql = "SHOW CREATE TABLE ".$table_to_copy;

    $res = $this->model->queryRow($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!filled($res['Create Table']))
        throw new Exception('Could not get the create code for '.$table_to_copy);

    $newCreateSql = preg_replace(array(
        '@CREATE TABLE `'.$table_to_copy.'`@',
        '@KEY `'.$table_to_copy.'(.*?)`@',
        '@CONSTRAINT `'.$table_to_copy.'(.*?)`@',
        '@AUTO_INCREMENT=(.*?) @',
    ), array(
        'CREATE TABLE `'.$new_table_name.'`',
        'KEY `'.$new_table_name.'$1`',
        'CONSTRAINT `'.$new_table_name.'$1`',
        'AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ',
    ), $res['Create Table']);

    return $this->model->exec($newCreateSql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on `table name`
2. Choose `open table`
3. Go to `Info Tab`

and the scroll down to see create table script

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name`
2. Press GO button
3. After show table, above the table ( +options ) Hyperlink is there.
4. Press (+options) Hyperlink then appear some options select (Full texts) => Press GO button.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the Database required
2. Select the tables you want to `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
3. Click on dropdown **With Selected:** and select **Show create**

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to export table in sql file.

Suppose my table is `abs_item_variations`

```
abs_item_variations ->structure -> propose table structure -> export -> Go
```

Answer (score -1):

Export whole database select format as SQL. Now, open that SQL file which you have downloaded using notepad, notepad++ or any editor. You will see all the tables and insert queries of your database. All scripts will be available there.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL workbench, you get the already created table script, by just right click on the specific table, then select `send to SQL editor>>create statement`. That's all you will get the create table script on the editor.

Answer (score -3):

One more way. Select the target table in the left panel in phpMyAdmin, click on Export tab, unselect Data block and click on Go button.