# how can I get the sql statements used to create a specific table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose if I have access to a mysql database, and there exists a table named "users", how could I get the sql statements used to create that specific table? Is there any way to do it by a simple command in mysql shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a create table script for an existing table in phpmyadmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739014/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` (mysql only)

Answer (score 0):

in MS SQL

It is pretty long but it is what I do when needed

```
declare @clms nvarchar(max)
declare @tbl nvarchar(max)='a1'


select @clms= coalesce(@clms,'(')+column_name+ ' '+data_type+

 case  when data_type in ('nvarchar','varchar','char') then '(255)' else '' end + ', '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=@tbl



 select 'create table ' + @tbl +left(@clms,len(@clms)-1)+')'
```