# How put list object from JSON in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I need to put and get data from `MySql` with spring boot (`Hibernate`, `Jackson`)

Sample `JSON`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Product1",
        "colors": [
            {
                "color": [
                    "#dddd33",
                    "#676767"
                ]
            },
            {
                "color": [
                    "#FFdDFF"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Same `JSON` I want to receive but added "id". What should I do to achieve this?

Object:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("colors")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product_id")
    private Set<Color> colors;
}

@Entity
public class Color {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Long product_id;

    @JsonProperty("color")
    @CollectionTable(name = "color", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "color_id"))
    @Column(name = "color")
    @ElementCollection
    @OrderBy
    private List<String> color;
}
```

This not work
I get error 
`java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: The issue is with your SQL tables most likely- can you post your table creation scripts?

Comment: The fact is that Hibernate creates tables automatically.

Comment: You can always generate `CREATE SCRIPT` from already created table in `MySQL`. [How to generate a create table script for an existing table in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739014/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table-in-phpmyadmin). Also take a look on: [Why should not use the AUTO JPA GenerationType with MySQL and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/)