# Create a table and specify data types according to an existing query

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like this

[image]

this table is the result of a query from another larger table stored in my database
All I want is to create a table like this one above and specify for each column a custom format and store it into my database

I know that I could do create table mytab as select ... etc
however i don't know how to specify the column formats that I want in mysql

could you please help ?

Comment: I removed the BigQuery tag because your question explicitly mentions MySQL.  There is really no such thing as a data format, so your question is unclear.

Comment: You don't specify formatting in database table definitions. That's done in the applications that display the results of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming with column formats you mean data types: Use `CAST` to cast to the desired data type.

```
create new_table as
  select
    cast( a.metrique as varchar(100) ) as metrique,
    cast( b.nombre_de_lignes as int ) as cote_de_lignes, ...
  from ...
```

Comment: Yes, obviously :-) But as Barmar pointed out in the request comments, we don't call these formats, but types. Formats, e.g. a date formatted '2.3.2021' or '03/02/2021', are applied later, usually (and often automatically) by your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the query sql, you should be able to do a `select into` to store the results in a table.  Add a `LIMIT` clause to just store one row.  You could then do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` ([from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739014/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table-in-phpmyadmin)) to get the SQL for creating the table.   It would be up to you to figure out what your primary key should be.

Answer (score 0):

You may specify columns properties completely or partially. Like there is no SELECT part, and you simply create empty table.

I.e. like

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ({any definitions allowed in table creation query:
                          columns specifications, indices, constraints, FKs, etc.})
SELECT ...
```

In this form each output column in SELECT must have alias which matches according column name defined in CREATE TABLE part. If alias is absent in the structure then a column with the name==alias will be added to the table definition with dynamically formed properties.